# Outlook add 1px right to cell image

Tags: outlook, html-email, newsletter, email-client

I'm using outlook 2013 and I want to create email signature.

When I finished coding I found a 1px gap appear right to the image inside a table cell.

I gave that cell a background color to see if the problem from the image or from the cell itself.

I don't know if it a padding or its a right transparent border.

I search a lot for two days here and in other websites and nothing fixed.

I create another template to demonstrate this gap and here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <style type="text/css">
         table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
        </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table width="234" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
    <td width="117" height="33" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;margin:0;border:none;">
     <img src="http://amraymancom.ipage.com/signtures/mazaya/images/mazaya-logo.png" border="0" width="117" height="33" border="0" style="display:block;border:none;"/>
    </td>
    <td width="117" height="33" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;margin:0;border:none;">
     <img src="http://amraymancom.ipage.com/signtures/mazaya/images/mazaya-logo.png" border="0" width="117" height="33" border="0" style="display:block;border:none;"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

And here's a screenshot to the cell gap:

[image: Outlook Cell Gap]

I know that coding for Outlook is a headache but I would appreciate your help if you explain to me why this gap appear and what should I do to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <style type="text/css">
            table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="234" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" width="117" height="33" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;margin:0;border:none;">
                    <img src="http://amraymancom.ipage.com/signtures/mazaya/images/mazaya-logo.png" border="0" width="117" height="33" border="0" style="display:block;border:none;"/>
                </td>
                <td align="left" width="117" height="33" style="border-collapse:collapse;padding:0;margin:0;border:none;">
                    <img src="http://amraymancom.ipage.com/signtures/mazaya/images/mazaya-logo.png" border="0" width="117" height="33" border="0" style="display:block;border:none;"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'd try this. This isn't removing the gap, but I added `align="left"` to the td's , so the gap will be on the right and not in between. Also I would suggest to save both images as one. This makes sure it will always display correctly and will make loading times faster, as it saves on memory space.

Also since the images are on a white background maybe add them as jpg. For Email signatures its important to save as much space as possible, since you are sometimes mailing to mobile phones and you you send you signature again with each answer in each conversation.

Comment: Hi Niklas,

Thanks for reply.
I want to create Email Signature and I found 1px as a gap between the logo and a horizontal line.
The Signature https://s30.postimg.org/51sitipzl/Gap.jpg
So I want to remove this gap.

Comment: Yes for the two cells